# ASP.NET Membership multiple signed in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

Is there any way (Via IFRAME or something like that) to enable me browse to 2 different pages on the same browser on 2 different accounts in the ASP.NET membership?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much an ASP.Net authentication issue as much as a cookies issue, as the browser will always send the same cookies when on a single domain. Perhaps you could have an alternative url for your site so that a 2nd page can log in with this different account?

Comment: I think that's what i'll do. Thanks!